# Can't change MediaTimeline's RepeatBehavior after it's started?

Tags: wpf, media-player, mediaelement, timeline

I'm running a MediaElement using MediaTimeline and MediaClock. However, when I change the RepeatBehavior after it's started it has no effect, I.e. When set to RepeatBehavior.Forever and Begin(), changing to RepeatBehavior(1) has no effect - the timeline continues forever. Likewise if the timeline is set to RepeatBehavior(1) changing it to RepeatBehavior.Forever afetr the clock has started also has no effect and the timeline stops at it's original Duration.

It's like the Duration doesn't get updated with these changes. Yet I cannot change Duration either.

Is there any way to change repeatbehavior after the clock has started?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try stopping animation, changing RepeatBehaviour and the launching animation from the same point where it stopped, so the user doesn't notice that it stopped.

Comment: Haven't tried it since I've moved onto the WMP ActiveX but I believe this is the answer. Cheers!